# Gamma PNL for Convertible Bond

Tags: gamma, convertible-bond, pnl

so just trying to compute gamma PNL for some CB positions using Bloomberg data for delta/gamma.
for a CB, BBG has delta 0.74 and Gamma 0.00524. if I want to compute the delta PNL and Gamma PNL for a position with market value $2,500,000(not face value)

with equity shock of 15%, i.e. the underlying stock price moves up by 15%. then it should clear that the delta PNL is given:
15% x 0.74 x 2,500,000 = $277,500.

that is to say, the CB price will move up by 15%*0.74 = 11.1%, hence we gain 11.1% from the current MV which is the delta pnl $277,500.

as the underlying stock price moves up, the CB's delta also changes, which is given by Gamma.
In this case the Gamma will be the absolute change in the delta percentage given a one percent change in the underlying stock price of the convertible.

Gamma is 0.00524, so given the 15% underlying stock move, the CB's delta will increase by 0.00524*15=0.0786. so after the move the CB's delta is 0.74+0.0786 = 0.8186

now the gamma PNL, in my limited understanding, would be (0.5 * 15 * 0.00524) * 0.15 * $MV = 14,737
so basically (0.5 * 15 * 0.00524) is just half of the delta move.

anyone has any comments or better interpretation of the gamma PNL here? or share any formulas by using this example? Many thanks